# Error coming in this CreateObject from com types?

Tags: python, comtypes, pyttsx3

Well here is my Simple Code:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
engine = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
#stream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
```

And this much errors comes.

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
return *win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'ctypes.wintypes.LP_c_long'>), 0)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python\cv2_tutorials\Text to Speech\text2speech.py", line 2, in 
engine = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client_*init**.py", line 250, in CreateObject
return *manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client_*init**.py", line 188, in *manage
obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client_*init**.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
mod = GetModule(tlib)
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client_generate.py", line 118, in GetModule
mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client_generate.py", line 198, in _CreateWrapper mod = my_import(fullname)
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client_generate.py", line 19, in *my_import
return **import**(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 438, in 
ISpeechBaseStream.*methods* = [
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes_*init**.py", line 323, in **setattr**
self.*make_methods(value)
File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes_*init**.py", line 692, in *make_methods
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
File "E:\Python\lib\ctypes_*init**.py", line 125, in WINFUNCTYPE
class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 1 in *argtypes* passes a union by value, which is unsupported.**

I know one thing that it is very simple mistake but i can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the Answer of my Own Question
and the Answer is very Simple :-
**Just Uninstall the pyttsx3 and comtypes : **

```
pip uninstall pyttsx3
pip uninstall comtypes
```

**and Then Reinstall Them by typing this : **

```
pip install comtypes
pip install -Iv pyttsx3==2.6 -U
```

It'll solve the problem ,thank me later